# Fade out, filter, than fade in items one be one

Tags: javascript, css, animation, filter

I'm trying to create a filtering animation in flexbox/grid layout.

The main issue is that items are already present in the container. So I had to use several set timeout functions but it seems to be overcomplicated. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Or should I explore moving items to another container and showing / hiding the clones?

```js
document.querySelector('.filter').addEventListener('click', function (){
  
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item').forEach(item => {
    item.classList.add('hidden');
    
    /* wait until animation ends */
     setTimeout(function () {
            item.classList.add('fully-hidden');
     }, 300)
  });
  
  items = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item').forEach(item => {
    if(!item.classList.contains('will-hide')) {
      items.push(item);
    }
  });
  
  
  setTimeout(function () {
            var itemsLength = items.length;
            items.forEach((item, index)=> {
              
              
               setTimeout(function () {
               
                    /* make item visible */
                    item.classList.remove('fully-hidden');

                     /* run animation */
                    setTimeout(function (){
                         item.classList.remove('hidden')
                    }, 100);

                }, index * 100)
  
            });
 }, 301)
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}

.grid-item {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.333% - 24px);
  padding: 12px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

  img {
   width: 100%; 
  }

.grid-item.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatey(20px);
}

.grid-item.fully-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <button class="filter">Filter</button>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item ">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1677019441418-a8485f977ca4?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY5MDQ2MTUxMA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=1080">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1688109511117-7f1a7def4567?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY5MDQ2MTg0OA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=1080">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item will-hide">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1690086142286-caccce218c0e?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY5MDQ2MTg2NA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=1080">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item will-hide">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item will-hide">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  </div>
 
    <div class="grid-item will-hide">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  </div>
 
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What? I'm so confused. What do you mean the items are already present in the container?

Comment: I mean that if you do filtering / load items via AJAX you can just replace the existing items which is easier to animate. Here you need to fade in & out same items.

Comment: "it seems to be overcomplicated. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?" You could use a JS library like [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/) to make the animations clearer/easier. Are you open to using a JS library?

Comment: I'm open — until it's not too big, because the whole idea was not to load Isotope :)